# Wordpress multisite dupliate sites in admin dropdown

Tags: wordpress, multisite

We have had this one site for a while, it has multisite setup. In the admin panel under the drop down it has the main site replicated in the menu over and over for each multi site on a sub-domain, including the url. This site has been updated over many versions of wp. A few developers took a crack at it but no one has figured how what is causing it, now its in my lap. The site functions as expected and is fully updated along with all its plugins. Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does it still happen if you disable all the plugins?

Comment: I take it each menu actually points to the correct site in the network and that you can click around the network using the menu still? Or do they all point at the main site?

Comment: They point to the main site, the only way to get to the child sites is to click Network Admin > Sites.